# Locate OpenCV-3's jar for use with Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, opencv

I am trying to get started with **OpenCV 3.0.0**. I would like to write in Java and I would like to use Eclipse.

The trouble is that the [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/introduction/java_eclipse/java_eclipse.html#java-eclipse) seems to be outdated. It claims that the **JAR** file that I need can be found at `OpenCV-2.4.6\build\java\`, however in **3.0** I don't see a `build` directory at all.

Where can I find the **JAR** file to add to my **Java** project so that I may make use of **OpenCV-3.0.0**?